# RxJS observe array and abort requests on change

Tags: javascript, rxjs, fetch-api

I have an array, that changes depending on user input. E.g. user clicks select button and I rewrite array when it happens. I'm doing fetch request once array fits requirements, but I want to reduce amount of requests, because user may quickly select many fields and only one request is needed, when user actually stops selecting fields. Therefore I am using switchMap, but I can't get it working.

```
const source$ = from(selected);
source$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  switchMap(() => {
    if(selected.length > 1) {
      const formatted = selected.map(s => s.id);
      fetch(`${url}/getParams`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ formatted })
      }).then(response => toCompare(response.json()));
    }
  })
);
```

Note, that selected is my array and I'm not doing push/pop, but I rewrite the array completely but using useState from React Hooks.

Comment: `I can't get it working` - what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @iofjuupasli meaning it actually does not work, I put console.log into switchMap and I don't get any output, so I assume it never gets called.

Comment: I think that is because of laziness of rxjs. You need to `subscribe` to stream that returned from `pipe`

Comment: @iofjuupasli could you please tell me how to subscribe correctly?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Rx.js doesn't run streams until there is at least one listener to it.

To add listener there is [`subscribe`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Subscribable#subscribe) method on all streams

```
const source$ = from(selected);
source$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
)
.subscribe(() => {
  if(selected.length > 1) {
    const formatted = selected.map(s => s.id);
    fetch(`${url}/getParams`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ formatted })
    }).then(response => toCompare(response.json()));
  }
});
```